# Question about Square Integrable Semimartingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Let $B = (B_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ be a Brownian motion and $\alpha = (\alpha_t)_{t \in [0,T]} $ be progressively measurable. Let
$$
X = \int_0^\cdot \alpha_t dt + \int_0^\cdot \alpha_tdB_t.
$$
If $\alpha$ satisfies
$$
E\left[ \int_0^T |\alpha_t|^2 dt \right] < \infty,
$$
then $X$ is bounded in $L^2.$ Is the reverse implication also true?

Comment: Yeah, it’s true

Comment: Note that you need some integrability condition on $\alpha$ to ensure that the integrals $\int_0^T \alpha_t \, dt$ and $\int_0^T \alpha_t \, dB_t$ exist; this means that already the well-definedness of $X$ gives information on the integrability of $\alpha$.